# Binding variables in point-free Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have been experimenting with the point-free style in js recently, and really enjoying how it makes me look at programming in general. As an exercise (in frustration, mainly) I’ve been rebuilding my personal site builder. Stylistically I like the main program as:

```
//MAIN
const inputPosts = read(POSTS_PATH);
const inputPages = read(PAGES_PATH);

• build all the page & post templates
• output all the pages
```

But, because of this, glob & fs need to be in sync mode. However, now I lose sight of the file path in readFile, and currently have it hard coded as POSTS_PATH (*yuck*).

```
const glob    = require('glob');
const fs      = require('fs');

const POSTS_PATH     = "content/posts/";
const PAGES_PATH     = "content/pages/";


const comp = (f, g) => x => f(g(x));
const map = f => list => list.map(f);

function findFiles(path) {
  const files = glob.sync("*.md", { cwd: path });
  return files;
}

function readFile(file){
  return fs.readFileSync(POSTS_PATH + file, {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  });
}

const read = comp(map(readFile), findFiles);

const inputPosts = read(POSTS_PATH);
```

If I were using the non-sync version I could bind path to glob's callback to readFile, and I could return an array from findFiles:

```
return [path, files]
```

But then it gets really messy.

Any way of keeping this simple and accessing path from within readFile?

Comment: "*glob & fs need to be in sync mode*" - why do you think that? Use promises to do asynchronous functional programming.

Comment: Your quotes and apostrophes are invalid. Don't write code in a word processor.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I lose sight of the file path in readFile*"?

Comment: Thanks for your responses Bergi. I’m getting mixed messages from my reading re: promises being functional, so I am trying to do without them for this exercise. Odd about the quotes/apostrophes — it was copied/pasted from brackets.

Comment: Path is passed to findFiles, and because the sync version returns an array, it is only the array that is then passed to readFile, and I lose the path variable.

Comment: Could you concatenate the path in `findFiles`? Something along the lines of `return files.map(file => path + '/' + file)`?

Comment: Thomas you’re a blimmin’ genius. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam but you're using `map`, so if  `findFiles` returns an array then `readFile` will be called with a single file name? Everything seems to be working. If you want to avoid `POSTS_PATH` in `readFile`, then you probably should make `findFiles` return an array of full paths.

Comment: If you don't like promises because they're partly OO instead of purely functional then use callbacks (regular node.js async functions). Callbacks are monads so they're definitely functional.

Comment: @Adam I provided a functional answer to a similar question here: [make a flat json from a tree json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37319211/633183). I think you will find the answer very helpful and understand that Promises *are* indeed a functional utility.

Comment: @naomik That makes great reading — thanks for the pointers

Comment: @Adam if you have any questions about it, I'm happy to help